# Grails 2.4.4 : hasOne is not solving the Bi-directional relationship

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have two tables **Users** and **Role**

These two tables should have bi-directional relationship for security purposes, so I have followed **hasOne** combination in Users table and **belongs to** in Role table. But bi-directional relationship is not happening.

Can anyone please help in this ?

```
class User
{

    Long number
    Integer inhabitants

    static hasOne = [ role: Role]

    static constraints = {
        role nullable: true, unique: true
    }
}

class Role
{

     Users user
     static belongsTo = [user: Users ] 
     static constraints = {
     }
}
```

Comment: Users? You have: "class User..."

Comment: Are you using Grails plugin "spring-security-core" ?

Answer (score 1):

Change `Role` to

```
class Role
{

     Users user
     static belongsTo = [user: User ] //you previously had Users here
     static constraints = {
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Grails Plugin spring-security-core and these two pages to help me setup. 
[Simplified Spring Security with Grails](http://spring.io/blog/2010/08/11/simplified-spring-security-with-grails/) and
[Tutorials - Reference Documentation](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v2/guide/tutorials.html).
It creates a table called UserRole that takes care of all that.

Comment: Thank you All.  i solved by keeping one class constraint null and another one is not null.